# Any flag to warn me in GCC if I initialize a struct but miss an element?

Tags: c, gcc, struct, warnings, compiler-warnings

Let's say I have this struct

```
typedef struct foo {
  int a;
  char b;
  char *c;
} foo;
```

and I want to create an initialized instance of the struct

```
foo bar = { .a = 7 .b = 'x' .c = "hello" };
```

However, what if I mess up and *forget* to initialize one of the elements of the structure I am initializing ... for example ...

```
foo bar = { .a = 7, .c = "hello" };
```

... I just forgot to initialize element "b" --- a mistake that is simple to detect in the example I gave, but in the case of more complex structs, especially under-development ones, this is definitely plausible.

Is there any flag that I could pass to [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) that would cause it to generate a warning if I do a screw-up like this?

Comment: `{ .a = 7 .b = 'x' .c = "hello" }` need `,`

Comment: Oh yes -- thanx BLUEPIXY --- I usually remember that, just forgot that when I was typing the question for some reason --- but thanks ...

Comment: GCC has `-Wmissing-field-initializers` (included in `-Wextra`) but for whatever reason doesn't apply it when designated initializers are used, only when 'positional' initializers are used.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Hope you don't mind my quoting this comment in my answer, but I did credit you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the *"old school"* ISO C way of initializing structs (when not compiling with `-std=c99`), gcc should give you a warning by default. Other than that, the gcc flag you need to set is `-Wmissing-field-initializers`, <strike>which is enabled by default AFAIK</strike> Which is *NOT* enabled by default, but part of `-Wextra`, as Michael Burr stated in his comment, provided you use the following syntax:

```
int main ( void )
{
    foo bar = {123, "foobar"};//failed to init char b member
    foo zar = {123, '\a'};//omitted c initialization 
    return 0;
}
```

This should issue the following warning:

```
warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
  foo bar = { 123, "foobar"};
warning: missing initializer for field ‘c’ of ‘foo’ [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
  foo zar = { 123, 'a'};
```

The major downside to this is, of course, that it makes your code harder to read, and maintain... not an insignificant down-side IMO...

If you can, and if the overhead isn't too bad, I'd simply write a function. Especially considering you have a `char *` member field, which may require heap-allocated memory:

```
foo * init_foo(foo *str, int a, char b, char *c)
{
    if (c == NULL) return NULL;// no char pointer passed
    if (str == NULL) str = malloc(sizeof *str);//function allocates struct, too
    str->a = a;
    str->b = b;
    str->c = calloc(strlen(c) + 1, sizeof *(str->c));//allocate char pointer
    strcpy(str->c, c);
    return str;
}
//optionally include custom free function:
void free_foo ( foo **f)
{
    if ((*f)->c != NULL) free((*f)->c);
    free(*f)
    *f = NULL;//init pointer to NULL
}
```

That'd be the safest way to go... call this function like so:

```
foo *new_foo = init_foo( NULL, 123, '\a', "string");//allocate new struct, set all members
//free like so:
free_foo(&new_foo);//pass pointer to pointer
foo stack_foo;
init_foo(&stack_foo, 123, '\a', "string");//initialize given struct
//only free .c member
free(stack_foo.c);
stack_foo.c = NULL;
```

At any rate, while developing, always compile using `-Wall` and, to be safe `--pedantic`, too...

Comment: Thanks, Elias. :-) The syntax you gave works. :-) And in the later example you gave of `foo bar = {123, 'a'}` --- that even gave me a warning if I passed the `-W` option to `gcc`. Of course, I got the idea of the `-W` option from the other person who answered --- but I consider your answer the better of the two, because the *other* person also gave *other* suggestions in his answer that caused the compiler to go completely belly-up even if I didn't forget *any* elements. So I'm selecting your answers as the "accepted answer".

Comment: To whomever down-voted: Please, I don't mind, but I would like to know why, perhaps link to some documentation I should read-up on

Comment: @user3080003: Cheers, note I've tried a couple of more things, and found a more reliable way, and the specific GCC flag that triggers the warnings. Also consider using the custom functions, if you can, because it does allow you to allocate the `char *` member, too if you want that...

Comment: I too wonder why someone down-voted your answer, Elias. I think you gave the best answer to this question.

Comment: Okay ---- now I'm having a problem with even the "--pedantic" option not giving the error I need.

Answer (score -1):

1. You have to pass "-W" option to gcc.
2. User bar.a instead of .a in your code.

you can see the following warning message if you compile code with "gcc -W test.c" command

```
test.c:11: warning: missing initializer
test.c:11: warning: (near initialization for âbar.câ)
```

Comment: Could you give a snippet of source-code as an example? I tried your suggestion, and there is clearly something I'm missing. When I replaced .a with bar.a, it gave me a syntax error. The C compiler doesn't allow that. And whether I use .a or bar.a, I didn't find any behavior differences caused by the -W option. With or without it the compiler went without complaint if I put just .a -- and with or without it I get the *same* error message if I put bar.a. If I'm missing something, an actual code example might clear it up, though.

Comment: The old `-W` switch and the more specific `-Wmissing-field-initializers` do not work with designated initializers.

Comment: `foo bar = { bar.a = 7, bar.c = "hello" }` does not do what you want. `bar.a = 7` is not a designated initializer. It is an assignment. This assignment is evaluated, and the result is 7. Then this value is used to initialize the first field, `a`. Similarly, `bar.c = "hello"` evaluates to the address of the string and is used to initialize the second field, `b`.

Comment: @MRaja: the example you give is *not* proper C syntax for initializing structures. If you attempt to do that when initializing a structure in *global* space, the compiler will inform you of this itself -- not via warning, but via *error*. If you do it inside of a function, then you can get *away* with this due to the same feature of C that lets you copy the value of `a` to both `b` and `c` by typing `c = ( b = a );` --- but bar.a is *not* the proper syntax for naming the element `a` within the structure-brackets when doing an initialization of a structure.

Comment: @user308003: Just tried to get the warning with -W option with the help of your code itself. I didn't worry about other things except to generate the warning for what I was looking for as we are not beginners :), if my answer is wrong then please ignore it. Thanks.